# Preg_match jquery script

Tags: php, jquery, preg-match

I want to get "bla bla bla" from this string

```
jQuery('#showcasecities').html("bla bla bla");
```

I've tried

```
preg_match_all("/jQuery(\'#showcasecities\').html(\"([^`]*?)\");/", $string, $matches);
```

no luck =( please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis. Instead, try this

```
preg_match_all("/jQuery\(\'#showcasecities\'\).html\((\"(.*?)\")\);/", $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("#jQuery\('\#showcasecities'\)\.html\((.*)\)#",$string,$matches);
```